# Pro Tem Moderator Announcement

Tags: discussion, moderators

Throughout the beta, we need members from the site whose focus is to engage the community, both in community-building issues and site management. That's why we select a few members from each community to act as temporary, provisional Moderators. You can read about the program here: [**Moderators Pro Tempore**](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/07/moderator-pro-tempore/).

It has... been some time since the site has begun. Normally, pro tem selection process is done very early in the site lifecycle (read: second week). However, in a mix of a mess largely centered around myself, the selection process not only took a while to get off foot, but also took a long time to complete.

All that is done now! I am pleased to announce that these members have stepped up and generously volunteered their time to help us assure that each community’s issues are properly addressed.

[image: tbm0115]
[image: Greenonline]
[image: StarWind0]

We want to make this site a huge success, and these members are great examples of exactly the type of people we need to make this site succeed. Please welcome them for the hard work and time they contribute.

Most of all, be respectful and understanding of the Moderators Pro Tem. Members of your community are volunteering their time and learning on the job. It’s a learning experience for everyone.

---

And thanks to these previous volunteer moderators too:

[image: Tormod Haugene]
[image: Ryan Carlyle]

Comment: Congratulations to all the mods! You have every support! Now grab all ye mops with the weight of ye blue diamonds... After 100 days there must be some spills to clean up :P

Comment: Congratulations, and many *thanks* for stepping up! Don't hesitate to let the rest of us know how we can/should chip in to help.

Comment: Congratulations, Greenonline and StarWind0! And good to see tbm0115 is still going strong. :-)

Comment: Excited to be on the team everyone. I'll be spending a lot of time in the mod channel. If people find it useful I might restart up the 3d printing channel where I can be more easily reached. I plan to also start a few campaigns to recruit more members by leveraging the 3d printing hobbyist facebook group I also moderate.

Comment: @StarWind0 And all others who read this, please join the [Public 3D printing room](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/79830/public-3d-printing-room)