# Should this site get additional moderators appointed?

Tags: discussion, moderators, flagging

My flag history shows that

- 6 "spam" flags aged away without review.
- 3 "rude/abusive" flags aged away without review.
- 2 "not an answer" flags were raised in February and are still pending. It's now April.

All this suggests that current moderators do not have enough time to handle flags. I think the site should try and get a couple more.

Comment: SE is a great community that I frequently use for other programming issues. It appears that those communities have more active members/moderators that are missing in the 3D Printing SE. You raise the waiving of raised flags, but there is much more going on. E.g. many topics with correct answers do not have accepted answers, questions do not receive much vote ups, nor do good answers. Accepting valid answers may also may be a task for moderators, but I understood that is not technically feasible. It is fair to start a discussion on this problem, but I think that there are too few active members

Comment: FWIW, I've had 4 out of 8 spam flags age away, but apart from that 24 other types of flags were dealt with reasonably promptly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some new moderators were appointed yesterday, see [Pro Tem Moderator Announcement](https://3dprinting.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/135/pro-tem-moderator-announcement). Hopefully the new moderators can keep up the sterling work that the previous moderators have provided up to now... :-)

After a minor marathon session of clearing the backlog, all flags have now been cleared. Hopefully in a way that keeps everyone happy:

- Some (one or two) questions were migrated to Engineering or Blender, after requests were thrown over to moderators on other sites, and some others were left "as is", as they have garnered some answers here on 3D Printing.
- Some short/terse answers (which were useful/informative) have been converted to comments, others (which were not so helpful) were deleted.
- Some sprawling comments threads/chats have been shortened/deleted
- Some "additional information" comments have been moved into the questions to which they pertain
- Some "issue resolved" updates to questions have been turned into community wiki answers

No information has hopefully been lost. If anything seems to have gone missing, please leave a comment below.

Comment: Thanks for cleaning up the backlog, keep up the good work! The only downside is that many old post came back to top again, I wish SE could let moderators edit questions without bringing them to the top again.

Comment: @0scar - yes, that is an issue that I came up against on SE.Arduino. Whilst I liked to go around fixing typos and mistakes in old questions, just to improve the general presentation of the site, it brought those posts to the top of the 'Active" list, and I received some angry complaints about making "noise" - which was rather unfortunate. You are right, it would be good if there was a way of editing that prevented the post becoming active (such as a "Non-active edit" checkbox or button), although that might lead to other issues (secret/stealth edits).

Comment: @0scar - I'll raise a issue on SE.Meta later about it, but I doubt that much will come of it, as there would be development work required for potentially little gain (apart from making the site look tidy). It is, indeed, a bit of a conundrum.

Comment: I realize that this may not get attention from SE as their reasoning would be that having active users and active moderators should prevent this from happening as edits should be made soon after posting of the question/answer. But it might be a handy feature in some cases, thanks for bringing it to SE.

Comment: @0scar - Please see [Editing without bumping](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/310860/editing-without-bumping) :-)